# Google Search Console (Mobile Usability) is incorrectly rendering page content too narrow, thus triggering the "Text is too small to read" error

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, google-search-console

All the articles on our blog are triggering the "Text too small to read" error in Google Search Console (Mobile Usability).

We were not able to validate this issue upon checking ourselves --

[image: Article screenshot from Android phone]

However, when view the same tested page in Google Search Console and view the screenshot, we see that the Googlebot smartphone rendering is compressing the content to about 1/3rd of the viewport --

[image: Screenshot from Google Search Console]

Here is the source code related to the example in the screenshots --

https://jsbin.com/munofohoke/edit?html,js,output

```
<a class="jsbin-embed" href="https://jsbin.com/munofohoke/embed?html,js,output">Finding Corporate Philanthropy a Challenge? Let This Primer Guide You | flevy.com/blog on jsbin.com</a><script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/embed.min.js?4.1.8"></script>
```

Any idea on how we can fix this?

The source code is the full webpage, as we are unable to replicate the Google Search Console issue locally.  We are using Wordpress and the Canvas WooTheme.

Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code with the problem is linked externally. Please [edit] this question to include the [minimal code that exhibits the issue](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. [Code linked externally may not be permanently available, and may not be licensed such that it can be used in answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Stephen.  I've edited the post to include a link to the source code of the example.  Since we are unable to replicate the issue as seen in the Google Search Console screenshot, we aren't able to reduce the code any further.

Comment: A link to jsbin isn't any better.  Please [edit] to paste it directly into your question.